# My Discord bot won't go online

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

I've already tried using the ' node index.js ' and ' node index ' commands, but I receive a syntax error message every time.

Here's what my .js file looks like. I'm using Visual Studio Code.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const TOKEN = "MYTOKENHERE";

var Discord = require("discord.js");
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on("message", function(message) {
    var channel = bot.channels.find("name", "general");
    channel.sendMessage("Hello Owner Just Restarted Me!");

    var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
    rule.minute = 0;
    rule.hour = [14, 19, 20];

    var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function() {
        bot.channels.get("id", channel).sendMessage("Testing");
    })

    console.log("Bot is ready.");
});

bot.login(TOKEN);
```

The error is:

> SyntaxError: Identifier 'Discord' has already been declared.

Comment: what isn't working? Have you authenticated your bot?

Comment: Please post the error as well, not just that you have one

Comment: You declare `Discord` twice, by the way

Comment: @MikeTung Yes, I've authenticated my bot already! It's been invited to the server, and I've also incorporated my special token in the code.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Oh, sorry! I'm new here, but I'll keep this in mind for next time. The error I receive on node.js looks like this:

    SyntaxError: Identifier 'Discord' has already been declared.

I'm assuming that's what you meant by your second comment? Does that mean I have to delete one of the instances of 'Discord'?

Comment: @MariellaDeDios you just need to delete the second `Discord`

Comment: @MariellaDeDios I edited your question to include the error. As Mike said, you should just remove `var Discord =` on line 5.

Comment: Remove 1 declaration of `Discord`. Check your code properly.

Answer (score 4):

As the error states `SyntaxError: Identifier 'Discord' has already been declared.`, it indicates that you have declared 'Discord' and then re-declared it... Which you have done here:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js"); // you've declared 'Discord' here

const TOKEN = "MYTOKENHERE";

var Discord = require("discord.js"); // and here again
```

Simply, remove the `var Discord = require("discord.js");` line to fix the error, here is what that should look like:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const TOKEN = "MYTOKENHERE";

var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on("message", function(message) {
    var channel = bot.channels.find("name", "general");
    channel.sendMessage("Hello Owner Just Restarted Me!");

    var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
    rule.minute = 0;
    rule.hour = [14, 19, 20];

    var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function() {
        bot.channels.get("id", channel).sendMessage("Testing");
    })

    console.log("Bot is ready.");
});

bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's in the syntax error itself, it is telling you that you have already declared a variable called Discord. In C++, the program would ignore the second variable. To fix this for javascript, you just have to take out one of the variables.
Hope this was helpful. FYI, different code editors usually DON'T have a different effect on your code.